# Execute Macro after background refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to have my two macros run *after* a background query refresh. I have a "main macro" that calls and executes them both, but I'd like it to be automated after the refresh. As of now, I've only been able to do this manually. Any thoughts?

My Macros:

```
Sub RefreshPivot()

Worksheets("MadeUpWorksheet").PivotTables("MadeUpPivot").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub

Sub CollapsePivot()

    Dim pT As PivotTable
    Dim pF As PivotField

    Set pT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MadeUpWorksheet").PivotTables(1)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    With pT
        For Each pF In pT.RowFields
            pF.DrillTo pF.Name
        Next pF
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Worksheets("MadeUpWorksheet").PivotTables("MadeUpPivot")` the same with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MadeUpWorksheet").PivotTables(1)`? If so, please forget about the third `Sub` calling both ones you show and place in `CollapsePivot`, after `Set pT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MadeUpWorksheet").PivotTables(1)`:  `pT.BackgroundQuery = False`, `Pt.Cache.Refresh` followed by `DoEvents`. Theoretically, it should wait until the refresh is done. Then, the iteration (starting `With pT`) should work as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unchecking the "enable background refresh" works like a charm in the calling function. I couldn't wrap my head around the manual execution of the background refresh if it was unchecked... but, it works. Thanks!